# No module name "Custom packages"

Tags: airflow

```
my_airflow_project/
├── dags/
│   ├── my_dag.py
│   ├── another_dag.py
├── plugins/
│   ├── operators/
│   │   ├── my_custom_operator.py
│   ├── sensors/
│   │   ├── my_custom_sensor.py
├
```

Call the function in the my_custom_sensor in the another_dag.py and report an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plugins'
, the configuration file airflow.cfg there is a path to define pugins

How to solve this problem

Comment: Hi there, do you mean that you have defined your plugin path in `airflow.cfg` but the module is not found somehow?